# Automatically drop records on insert if they violate constraint

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to set up a table with a constraint on it, but when I insert records, I don't want to get any constraint violation errors. I would like SQL to quietly drop any records that aren't unique, but carry on inserting those that can be inserted.

for example....

```
create table table1
(value1 int,
value2 int,
constraint uc_tab1 Unique (value1,value2)
)

create table table2
(value1 int,
value2 int
)

insert into table2 (value1,value2)
select 1,1
union all 
select 2,1
union all
select 3,1
union all
select 1,1

insert into table1
select value1,value2 from table2
```

At the moment, this will fall over on a violation constraint. I want to suppress that error, so that table1 contains...

```
1,1

2,1

3,1
```

(in this example, I could just do a group by on table2, but in my actual application that isn't really viable)

I vaguely remember reading something about this years ago, but I might have imagined it. Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` [index option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), although personally I think it is better to find another way of solving your problem.

You can set it to `ON` to only generate warnings for inserted rows that violate the unique constraint instead of generating errors.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I was thinking about.

Comment: @Bakhesh You can thank me best by checking the checkmark next to my answer :)

Comment: Have done so. Apologies, my stack overflow etiquette is a bit rusty

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this, you will lose data very easily

Instead try to change your application so it only inserts valid data isntead of dropping incorrect data

Comment: In this scenario, we won't, because it's already in there. We only need one example. 

I can join the insert table to the original table to look for duplicates, but our table sizes are huge, and I think this would be very slow

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `MERGE` statement. It's complex, but can be made to do what you are describing.

(There is or was something that could cause an `INSERT` statement to continue to insert data even if some rows could not be inserted, but for the life of me I can't find it in BOL or recall what it was called. I'm pretty sure it raised errors anyway, and it always sounded like a horrible idea to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying Ignore_Dup_Key when I created my constraint did the trick. In the above example, I changed the table1 definition to....

create table table1
(value1 int,
value2 int,
constraint uc_tab1 Unique (value1,value2) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)

And it worked perfectly